# wiring for garage lights

Tags: wiring, garage

I would like to change the light setup in my garage. Right now there is one switch that controls 3 lights, I would like to change to 3 Switchs that controls 6 lights.... 2 lights per one switch, can you show me a simple way to do this

Comment: Can you post photos and/or a diagram of the existing setup? Also, where do you want to put the switches and lights, and are the garage walls finished or not?

Comment: This is really easy take power to each of the 2 lights from 1 switch  or 3 total if this is two complex hire a electrician .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take power to each switch. Then feed neutral, ground, and a switched hot to each set of lights.

[image]
<sup>Grounds not shown for simplicity</sup>